# Do self-referential generics violate polymorphism?

Tags: java, generics

A self-referential type can be defined in Java as such

```
interface Foo<F extends Foo<F>> { F self(); }
```

This will lock a specific implementation of `Foo` to its correspondent class hierarchy.
I.e I cannot longer define another `Foo` (by implementing this interface again) which will be compatible with previously implemented one.

Why such behavior is desirable? Does it violate polymorphism?

Example in question:

```
class X implements Foo<X> { ... }
class Y extends X { ... }
```

If `X` gets deprecated, it's impossible to replace it with another implementation of `Foo`. 
I have to provide a new implementation of `Foo`, rewrite `Y` and remove `X` at the same time. 
The whole hierarchy of `X` and `Y` is not replaceable by another one, hence polymorphism is violated.

Comment: What exactly does "violate polymorphism" mean? The primary use is that you can define _more_ methods on a specific implementation and then chain calls; configuration builders are a very common case, where builders might have shared parameters such as timeouts but also custom parameters for individual services.

Comment: This is sometimes known as [F-Bounded Quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) and it shows up in other places such as the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern in C++. It is unclear what it is you believe this prevents you from doing. Could you give a more complete example?

Comment: By "violate polymorphism" I mean that I'm no longer able to define a new hierarchy of classes, and replace with it the existing one.

Comment: @andreoss does `final` also violate polymorphism?

Comment: @AndyTurner Depends. If there is an interface for that `final` class and I can replace any instance of it with a new implementation, than no. But `java.lang.String` or `java.io.Console` can be an example of non-polymorphic class, both are final and irreplaceable